# OSX Lion -- NSEvent when Launchpad is entered

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I am writing a Mac app that uses a window which is glued to the foreground of the screen. I am listening for the `NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification` to detect when it is appropriate to hide the window.

For almost every purpose -- including when a different application enters focus -- this works perfectly.

On OSX Lion there is an idiosyncrasy. When my window is open and glued to the foreground, and then the user selects the `Launchpad` icon from the dock to expand the `Launchpad`, my window stays in the foreground, even over `Launchpad`. It appears that `Launchpad` is implemented as some sort of screen overlay rather than a window that would take focus.

Does anyone have any solution to detect when `Launchpad` enters focus so that I can dismiss my window?

Comment: I would recommend that you simply put your window at a lower window level. If it's over Launchpad, it's too high.

Comment: Yes, what level are you setting your window to?

Comment: You guys are both right. It was `NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel`. I lowered it a notch to `NSModalPanelWindowLevel` and that seems to have done the trick. If one of you answers i'll accept.